# Удалил netplan в linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

пытался настроить статический ip в linux (Я новичок в этой ОС), случайно изменил yaml файл из папки netplan, теперь не могу зайти в инет и у меня пропал ip (или просто перестал показываться). Пробывал этот файл удалять, менять, не помогло. Помогите, пожалуйста, восстановить этот файл или создать и применить новый, по возможности доступным для новичка языком, спасибо.

Comment: что за папка (вообще то каталог) netplan?

Comment: А на что пробовали менять-то? Покажите содержимое, которое вы писали - посмотрим и подскажем что не так

Comment: @KoVadim это такое очередное проявление NIH в убунте 18.04

Comment: @andreymal Создал новый файл - 01-netcfg.yaml в каталоге etc/netplan, со следующим содержимым:

Comment: network: version 2 renderer:networkd ethernets: enp7s0: dhcp4: no ( пробелы везде правильно поставил, везде по 2, с телефона просто неудобно)

Answer (score 2):

```
> ifconfig
```

смотрите названия сетевой катры

```
>sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

напишете примерно так: (у меня на сервере)

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:   # название сетевухи
            addresses: [192.168.0.150/24]  # ваш статический адрес
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1  # адрес роутера (откуда инет)
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
            dhcp4: no
    version: 2
```

применяете так:

```
>sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: добрый день, спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, не помогло, посмотрите пж, мб где-то не то сделал. https://yadi.sk/i/9lA2mnL8ToS7Pw

Comment: в gateway (адрес роутера) - описка или у вашего роутера совсем другоие адреса

Comment: если не знаете адрес роутера, значит не меняли и адрес находится на дне: вариант роутер 192.168.0.1 и ваш 192.168.0.150/24. Или у роутера 192.168.1.1 и ваш - 192.168.1.150/24. После успеха, заходите в сам роутер и там прописываете статический адрес (такой-же).

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo netplan generate
```

Вот хорошая [статья](http://blog.sedicomm.com/2018/05/25/kak-nastroit-staticheskij-ip-adres-v-ubuntu-18-04/) по этому вопросу.